# Why is the ValidationRule base constructor required for the ValidationRule derived class to be called on LostFocus?

Tags: .net, wpf, validation, lostfocus, validationrule

I am trying to understand why if I do not call the `ValidationRule` base constructor, like

```
public GrainWeightValidate() : base(ValidationStep.UpdatedValue, true) { }
```

then when the Validation rule *should* be called, upon `LostFocus` (using on a `TextBox` as shown below), the `Validate` function is not called *at all* when the `TextBox` does indeed lose focus.  However, if I change `UpdateSourceTrigger` below to `PropertyChanged`, then `GrainWeightValidate.Validate()` is called, but infinitely until there is a stack overflow.  Following is the relevant XAML:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4">
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <TextBox Name="GrainWeightTextBox" MinWidth="23">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:GrainWeightValidate/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running in a StackOverflowException because of the `RelativeSource Self` binding. Validation isn't the source of your error.

Here you are Binding the `Text` `DependencyProperty` ([`TextProperty`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBox.cs.html#47e834d7646f17c6)) of the `TextBox` to the [`Text`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBox.cs.html#7b5be95f7a8f33a8) property of the same TextBox. The `Text` property in it's implementation just call the corresponding `DependencyProperty`:

So when losing focus on the TextBox, the Bindings updates, and it updates `Text`, which updates the `TextProperty` `DependencyProperty`, which update `Text`, which updates the `TextProperty`... etc. etc.

Removes the `RelativeSource` attribute, and make the Path="..." value target a valid property on your ViewModel.

If you don't use MVVM, then you can maybe trick the Binding like this :

```
    <TextBox Name="GrainWeightTextBox" MinWidth="23">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding ElementName="GrainWeightTextBox" Path="Tag" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:GrainWeightValidate/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

And then, get your value in code behind by accessing the `Tag` property.
It's really really really dirty, but it should work....

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Unfortunately, the code is not using MVVM and for several reasons, I can't make the change right now. So I'm stuck with this situation.

Comment: Thanks for that hack - I will give that a try. What I was really looking for, though (sorry for not being more explicit in my question) is for understanding why ``GrainWeightValidate.Validate()`` is not being called *at all* when the ``TextBox`` loses focus, but if I change ``UpdateSourceTrigger`` to ``PropertyChanged``, then ``Validate()`` is called (albeit causing a SO). And then also why calling the ``ValidationRule`` base constructor as mentioned basically gets me the "right" behavior of ``PropertyChanged``.

Comment: I think in the first case, the Binding itself causes the SO, in the second case, the Validation after the binding causes the SO. For the ValidationStep value, it's on msdn : "UpdatedValue : Runs the ValidationRule after the source is updated."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.validationstep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx